# Android widget doesn't update automatically

Tags: android, json, android-appwidget

I am working on JSON.I parsed JSON and i can show my JSON **listview**(images and texts)and also I successfully created widget and i want to show my JSON's first items's title in my widget.i also wrote this code(if i drop widget then i can to show first title in widget) but widget does not updated .JSON's first item updated but widget's title does not updated .What is a wrong ? if anyone knows solution please help me thanks
This is a my code :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name="BriWidget"
        android:label="@string/widget1name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="com.eightbitcloud.example.widget.8BITCLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.brige.SpleshScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     </application>

</manifest>




public class BriWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE = "CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE";
RemoteViews remoteViews;
int appWidgetId;
public File file;
public Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // initializing widget layout
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_demo);

    // register for button event
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sync_button,
            buildButtonPendingIntent1(context));

    // updating view with initial data

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.desc, getDesc());

    // request for widget update
    pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
}

public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {

    MyWidgetIntentReceiver.clickCount++;

    // initiate widget update request
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    intent.setAction(WidgetUtils.WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent1(Context context) {
    ++MyWidgetIntentReceiver.clickCount;

    // initiate widget update request
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(WidgetUtils.WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private static CharSequence getDesc() {
    return "Beka";
}



public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, BriWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);
}
}


public class MyWidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static int clickCount = 0;
public static String CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE = "CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(WidgetUtils.WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION)) {
        updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(context);
    }
}

private void updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_demo);

    // updating view
    //remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, getTitle());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.desc, getDesc(""));

    // re-registering for click listener
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sync_button,
            BriWidget.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

    BriWidget
            .pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
}

private String getDesc(String abc) {
    abc = (MainActivity.itemList.get(0).get(MainActivity.KEY_title))
            .toString();

    return abc;
}

}



public class BRIgeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

private int screenSize;

public BRIgeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d,
        int screenSize) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.data = d;
    this.screenSize = screenSize;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView journal = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smalljournal);
    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle);
    TextView description = (TextView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription);
    ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smallthumb);
    TextView statId = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smallstatID);
    TextView DateTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smallDateTime);
    HashMap<String, String> itemList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    itemList = data.get(position);

    journal.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_journal));
    statId.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_statID));
    journal.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    String titleString = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_title);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    String DateTimeTxt = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate).replace(
            "T", " ");

    try {
        Date _d = df.parse(DateTimeTxt);
        SimpleDateFormat new_df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String _s = new_df.format(_d);
        DateTime.setText(_s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
        description.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    else
        description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    title.setText(titleString);
    title.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);
    description.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_description));
    description.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    String url = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_image);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, thumb_image);

    return vi;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public String URL = "********************************";

public static String KEY_title = "title";
public static String KEY_description = "description";
public static String KEY_image = "image";
public static String KEY_journal = "journal";
public static String KEY_JournalID = "JournalID";
public static String KEY_pubDate = "pubDate";
public static String KEY_statID = "statID";
public JSONArray jsonarray;
public ListView list;
public JSONParser jsonparser;
static BRIgeAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog pDialog, pDialog1;
static String fontPath2 = "font.ttf";
public static Typeface tf2;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
static final int DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION = 1;

;

public static String dateTime;
private ArrayList<Content> contents = new ArrayList<Content>();

public TransparentProgressDialog pd;
public HashMap<String, String> map;

private int screenSize;

public LoadDataAllChanelsToServer loadData;

AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
Writer writer;
public File yourFile;
View menu_Slide;

@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

    itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter = new BRIgeAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList, screenSize);

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(this,
            this));
    loadData = new LoadDataAllChanelsToServer();

    menu_Slide = (findViewById(R.id.menu_button));

    tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath2);

    pd = new TransparentProgressDialog(this, R.drawable.loader);
    loadData.execute();

}

private class LoadDataAllChanelsToServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        jsonparser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonparser.getJSONfromURL(URL);
        try {

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("journal", jsonobject.getString(KEY_journal));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString(KEY_image));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString(KEY_title));
                map.put("description",
                        jsonobject.getString(KEY_description));
                map.put("JournalID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_JournalID));
                map.put("pubDate", jsonobject.getString(KEY_pubDate));
                map.put("statID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_statID));

                Content cont = new Content(jsonobject.getString("journal"),
                        jsonobject.getString("image"),
                        jsonobject.getString("title"),
                        jsonobject.getString("pubDate"),
                        jsonobject.getString("description"),
                        jsonobject.getString("JournalID"),
                        jsonobject.getString("statID"));
                contents.add(cont);

                itemList.add(map);
                dateTime = itemList.get(itemList.size() - 1).get(
                        KEY_pubDate);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return itemList.toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            adapter = new BRIgeAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList,
                    screenSize);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    createDialog();

}

private void createDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDlg.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");

    alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

    alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();

                }

            }

    );

    alertDlg.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }

    });

    alertDlg.create().show();
}

}
```

what is a wrong? anyone know a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To update your widget after every particular interval of time use alarm manager.